# trying to draw a line with floating point x, y values in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am creating a graph drawing app and currently facing a problem drawing the edges from one node to the other.
The problem is that to draw the edge between two nodes I must find the points of intersection of the two nodes (circles) and the line intersecting their centers, which then gives me 4 (x, y) points, then by finding the two closest points that is where I draw the edge.
For this I made a function (No need to actually understand how it operates its just math):

```
    def computeIntersections(self, node1, node2):
        a, b = node1.x, node1.y
        c, d = node2.x, node2.y
        r1 = node1.radius
        r2 = node2.radius

        m = (d - b) / (c - a)

        g = 1+m**2

        xa = g
        xb = -(2*a*g)
        xc = g*a**2 - r1**2

        x1Node1 = (-xb + sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        x2Node1 = (-xb - sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        y1Node1 = m*(x1Node1 - a) + b
        y2Node1 = m*(x2Node1 - a) + b

        xa = g
        xb = -(2*c*g)
        xc = g*c**2 - r2**2

        x1Node2 = (-xb + sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        x2Node2 = (-xb - sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        y1Node2 = m*(x1Node2 - a) + b
        y2Node2 = m*(x2Node2 - a) + b

        node1Intersections = [(x1Node1, y1Node1), (x2Node1, y2Node1)]
        node2Intersections = [(x1Node2, y1Node2), (x2Node2, y2Node2)]

        distances = {}
        for point1 in node1Intersections:
            for point2 in node2Intersections:
                x1 = point1[0]; y1 = point1[1]
                x2 = point2[0]; y2 = point2[1]

                distance = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

                distances[distance] = (x1, y1, x2, y2)

        return distances[min(distances.keys())]
```

at the end it returns a list of 4 values: x1, y1, x2, y2 which will be used to draw the edge.
The issue is that these values are always floats, and the method I use to draw the edges is with the QPainter and drawLine method which takes integers only not floats, so I thought I could probably round it to the nearest int and no one would notice because the pixels are so small. This results in the edge looking something like this:

[image: Pic of the app]

As you can see the starting point of the edge goes inside the Node when its rounded so I was wondering if there could be a way to draw a line with floating point x, y coordinates or if there is a different way to do this entirely without the math that I wasn't aware of

EDIT:
Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QFrame, QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from math import sqrt
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 800)

        self.node1 = Node(self, 'A', 5, 100, 100)
        self.node2 = Node(self, 'B', 20, 700, 700)

    def computeIntersections(self, node1, node2):
        a, b = node1.x, node1.y
        c, d = node2.x, node2.y
        r1 = node1.radius
        r2 = node2.radius

        m = (d - b) / (c - a)

        g = 1+m**2

        xa = g
        xb = -(2*a*g)
        xc = g*a**2 - r1**2

        x1Node1 = (-xb + sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        x2Node1 = (-xb - sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        y1Node1 = m*(x1Node1 - a) + b
        y2Node1 = m*(x2Node1 - a) + b

        xa = g
        xb = -(2*c*g)
        xc = g*c**2 - r2**2

        x1Node2 = (-xb + sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        x2Node2 = (-xb - sqrt(xb**2 - 4*xa*xc)) / (2*xa)
        y1Node2 = m*(x1Node2 - a) + b
        y2Node2 = m*(x2Node2 - a) + b

        node1Intersections = [(x1Node1, y1Node1), (x2Node1, y2Node1)]
        node2Intersections = [(x1Node2, y1Node2), (x2Node2, y2Node2)]

        distances = {}
        for point1 in node1Intersections:
            for point2 in node2Intersections:
                x1 = point1[0]; y1 = point1[1]
                x2 = point2[0]; y2 = point2[1]

                distance = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

                distances[distance] = (x1, y1, x2, y2)

        return distances[min(distances.keys())]

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = [round(n) for n in self.computeIntersections(self.node1, self.node2)]
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        qp.end()

class Node(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, heuristic, x, y):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name
        self.heuristic = heuristic
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = 50

        self.initializeNode()
    
    def initializeNode(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.x-self.radius, self.y-self.radius, self.radius*2, self.radius*2)

        self.nodeName = QLabel(self.name, self)
        self.nodeName.setObjectName('nodeName')
        self.nodeName.setGeometry(25, 15, 50, 50)

        self.nodeHeuristic = QLabel(str(self.heuristic), self)
        self.nodeHeuristic.setObjectName('nodeHeuristic')
        self.nodeHeuristic.setGeometry(40, 70, 20, 20)

        self.setDefaultStyle()


    def setDefaultStyle(self):
        self.setStyleSheet(defaultStyle)

defaultStyle = """
    QFrame {
        border: 3px solid black;
        min-height: 100px;
        min-width: 100px;
        border-radius: 53px;
    }

    QFrame#nodeName {
        qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
        border: 0px;
        font-size: 30px;
        min-height: 50px;
        min-width: 50px;
    }

    QFrame#nodeHeuristic {
        height:10px;
        width:10px;
        min-height: 20px;
        min-width: 20px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
"""

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The problem you're showing doesn't seem to be caused by the usage of integers: the beginning of the line is off by more than a single pixel, so the problem is either in the way you draw the circles or you compute their coordinates. Please provide a [mre] with a basic `node` class definition and the painter implementation.

Comment: @musicamante Done. Please let me know if I should add anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with floating point values: as you can see, the line is off by more than a pixel, which wouldn't be caused by "imprecise" integer values.
The main cause is the fact that you've set a *border* for the widget with a specific width.

When a border is set from style sheets (or by the style when using QFrame subclasses), the actual *final* geometry includes the border width. If you just `print()` the `geometry()` of those nodes *after* they've been shown, you'll see that their size is 106x106, which is the actual size plus twice the border (left+right for the width and top+bottom for the height).

A simple workaround for your case is to consider those borders when preparing the values for the computation:

```py
    def computeIntersections(self, node1, node2):
        border = node1.frameWidth()
        a, b = node1.x + border, node1.y + border
        c, d = node2.x + border, node2.y + border
        r1 = node1.radius + border
        r2 = node2.radius + border
        # ...
```

Note that using widgets for complex custom drawings (and especially when dealing with multiple objects, advanced hierarchies and precise positioning), is normally discouraged: widgets are normally intended as standard interface elements and their implementation follows the same concept, which can cause problems if used in the "wrong" way (like what happened to you).

For the same reason, using child widgets with fixed geometries can cause unexpected problems (try setting the heuristic to a value with 3 or 4 digits and you'll see the result).

A better solution is to completely draw the elements with the QPainter functions, and compute the coordinates according to the contents. Note that, while your problem was not caused by the usage of integer values, it must be considered that all QPainter methods that use numeric arguments for coordinates accept integers only, and if you want to use floating points you need to use the floating point Qt classes: [QPointF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointf.html), [QLineF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinef.html), [QRectF](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html).

On the other hand, Qt provides simpler (and faster) methods to do connect two circles with a line that intersects their centers:

- create a QLineF that connects the centers of the two circles;
- get the *angle* of that line;
- create two lines for the two circles with the static [`fromPolar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinef.html#fromPolar), which will be the lines from the center of the circles to their circumference, along with the connection of their centers;
- draw a line between the *second* point of those two lines;

Since we obviously don't need the style sheet anymore, we can subclass from QWidget instead of QFrame.

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 800)

        self.node1 = Node(self, 'A', 5, 100, 100)
        self.node2 = Node(self, 'B', 20, 700, 700)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)

        # the angle between the two centers
        angle = QLineF(self.node1.center, self.node2.center).angle()

        # a line that uses the same angle and is equal to the radius
        first = QLineF.fromPolar(self.node1.radius, angle)
        # fromPolar always has the first point at (0, 0), so we need to
        # translate it to the center of the first circle
        startRadius = first.translated(self.node1.center)

        # the same as above, but with an inverted angle
        second = QLineF.fromPolar(self.node2.radius, angle + 180)
        endRadius = second.translated(self.node2.center)

        # draw the line connecting the end points of each radius
        qp.drawLine(startRadius.p2(), endRadius.p2())


class Node(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, heuristic, x, y):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name
        self.heuristic = heuristic
        self.center = QPoint(x, y)
        self.radius = 50
        self.setGeometry(x - 50, y - 50, 100, 100)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 3))
        # the circle is drawn inside the widget rectangle, so we need to draw
        # a circle that is smaller by half of the pen size
        margin = 1.5
        size = self.radius * 2 - margin * 2
        qp.drawEllipse(QRectF(margin, margin, size, size))
        
        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        qp.setFont(font)

        # a horizontally centered rectangle that is slightly above the
        # center, considering the font size
        nameHeight = QFontMetrics(font).ascent()
        nameRect = QRectF(0, self.height() / 2 - nameHeight, 
            self.width(), 30)
        qp.drawText(nameRect, Qt.AlignCenter, self.name)

        font.setPointSize(15)
        qp.setFont(font)
        fm = QFontMetrics(font)

        # the circle must contain the text, we need to add some margin
        heuText = ' ' + str(self.heuristic) + ' '
        heuSize = max(fm.height(), fm.horizontalAdvance(heuText))
        # the rect of the circle, placed at half its height from the bottom;
        # note that I used QRectF for precision
        heuRect = QRectF(self.width() / 2 - heuSize / 2, 
            self.height() - heuSize * 1.5, 
            heuSize, heuSize)
        qp.drawEllipse(heuRect)
        qp.drawText(heuRect, Qt.AlignCenter, heuText)
```

Final notes:

- in the long run, the whole custom QWidget implementation will result in much more complex issues; I strongly suggest you to switch to the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html), which also provides better mouse interaction and performance, especially if using the existing graphics items, like QGraphicsEllipseItem;
- [`x()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#x-prop) and [`y()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#y-prop) are existing, dynamic properties of all QWidgets, and you should not overwrite them;
- the QPainter used in `paintEvent()` gets automatically destroyed when the function returns, there is no need to explicitly call `end()`;
- if you used widgets in order to change the values of those labels, you can still do it by creating custom properties or even Qt properties, and then call `self.update()` in their setter functions; for these situations, using child widgets just for their object name or property setter/getters is not a comparable benefit;

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. The reason I went with widgets to draw the graph was because I wanted the application to be visually appealing so I thought using css would be a good idea to achieve this more easily. Basically all I want is for example to create a node on shift+click, create an edge on click from one node to the other, and to change the node labels, heuristics, and edge weights. These requirements are mostly done. Next there should be multiple search algorithm implementation which would color things like visited nodes and such as well as generate the solution tree.

Comment: So I feel like most of the work is done already with this (although problematic) but for now working solution. Do you still think it would be worth it to switch to the Graphics View at this point? I feel like what I am creating is not very complex, I also don't want to give up on the freedom of css styling

Comment: What is complex is the drawing aspect. Using widgets doesn't automatically make the UI "visually appealing" just because you used style sheets, as it completely depends on how you use them. As explained, such customized painting with widgets creates more drawbacks than benefits: besides problems like the border, for instance, placing the labels with fixed geometries (which completely ignores user fonts or system scaling) would potentially hide part of the text on some systems. Switching to the Graphics View is a possibility, but it has a steep learning curve, so it's up to you.

Comment: If you are at a good point with your project, I'd still suggest you to avoid the whole child-label approach, just like the style sheet usage (for this purpose, they can be completely ignored as shown in the code above). While my implementation of the `Node` object (which, at this point, could just inherit from QWidget instead of QFrame) might seem more complex, it's actually much more effective, as it automatically considers many aspects (including font sizes) and doesn't create any issue for the geometries or the computation of the node position and their "connections".

Comment: On the other hand, if you still have some work to do, "this works for now" is not acceptable. Sooner or later you'll probably find out other issues with that approach, which might force you to find terrible workarounds (which might not work that well) because it's too late to change it. As said, changing the name, heuristic and border is completely doable with my code: just create setter functions and call `update()` (if you want to change the border width, make that an instance attribute and use it for the `QPen()` and the `margin` value).